# How to customize Recepient name list in Native Share Dialog in Google Plus in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios7, google-plus

I want to send app request in Google Plus. I referred google plus sdk and i choosed nativesharedialog box. But my problem is, i want to customize this recepient screen (image attached below).

[image]

Here i want to show only my google plus friends. I don't want to show suggestions and circle lists. How to customize this one. I write this code to show google plus nativesharedialog box.

```
    [GPPShare sharedInstance].delegate = self;

    // Use the native share dialog in your app:
    shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];

    [shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.companyname.com"]];

    [shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"Check out my app, You'll love it!"];

    [shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"INVITE"];

    NSString *str_ID = (NSString *)[m_UserIdListMutArr objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

    [shareBuilder setPreselectedPeopleIDs:@[str_ID]];

    [shareBuilder open];
```

Please give me some idea to handle this process.